# How to include Java Code Block in Xtext DSL?

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

In an Xtext grammar I can include an Xbase code block using the `XExpression`/`XBlockExpression` types. How would I go to do the same with a Java code block? The included java should later be included in the Java generated from the DSL constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this now with JBase (https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/jbase). JBase was created specifically for the use case you described (see https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2972217) and can be incorporated with minor changes by extending JBase instead of XBase.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly include Java code blocks (unless you are prepared to write an entire Java grammar and corresponding tooling support, e.g. variable resolution or code generation).

However, Xbase code blocks can be translated into Java code blocks using built-in Xtext services in the model inferrer or using the XbaseCompiler. It is also possible to simply interpret it with the XbaseInterpreter class.

Finally, if you really need the Java code blocks, you could write them in .java files, and refer to them using JvmIdentifiableElements.

Comment: That is what I feared. I am aware of the xbase functionality and it is kind of a pity since xbase to java works but java to java not (and that though all Java tooling support is already present in eclipse) :D Background idea was that I could "enrich" java with additional functionality without having to bother all my good java developers here with another "programming language" to learn.

Comment: It is much harder to include Java code than it seems - except if you don't need the fancy features such as syntax highlighting, content assist, etc. JDT features a very performant, but hardly reusable tooling for this reason that is really hard to include in Xtext, that relies on a different technology. Alltogether, by introducing a new language it is easier to provide useful tooling.