# How to embed C++ code in a xtext DSL?

Tags: c++, eclipse, parsing, xtext

What is the proper way of handling C++ code blocks in Xtext/ANTLR?

We are writing an Xtext-based eclipse plugin for a DSL that supports adding C++ function-level code within well-defined scopes (mostly `serial { /* ... */ }` blocks) such as this:

```
module m {
  chare c {
    entry void foo() {
      serial {
        // C++ code block
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [here](https://charm.cs.illinois.edu/gerrit/gitweb?p=charm.git;a=blob;f=examples/charm%2B%2B/matmul/matmul.ci;h=3ab426a38f400f27955156ca5324386cc457b04d;hb=HEAD#l24) for a more comprehensive example. This is then handed over to an external tool to handle further compilation/linking steps, so we don't generate any code from eclipse.

The issue here is how to handle these C++ code blocks, especially given that they may contain braces of their own. This is very similar to [How to include Java Code Block in Xtext DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196448/how-to-include-java-code-block-in-xtext-dsl) but for now we are content with just ignoring that block (i.e. not having content assist or syntax highlighting is not ideal but acceptable.)

In our bison/flex-based tool this is done by sharing a variable between the parser and lexer that toggles a "C++ parsing mode" within certain grammar rules that makes the lexer return a CPROGRAM token for everything except the relevant delimiters (e.g. braces.) The natural translation seems to have a custom ANTLR lexer that uses semantic predicates to the same effect, e.g.

```
RULE_NON_BRACES: {in_braces}? ~('{' | '}')+;
```

as the first lexing rule, but I cannot find how to access that global variable from the Xtext grammar since there doesn't seem to be a concept of "rule action" as in bison. There are other non-"serial" grammar contexts where C++ code is expected, so there needs to be some coordination between the parser and lexer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems more focused on how the DSL lexer avoids getting lost in C++ code.  The basic answer is you need to *match* parentheses (e.g, ensure that they nest properly).

I don't know how you define an Xtext/ANTLR lexical rule to do that; I presume there is an ugly way to drop down into procedural code and start reading characters one-by-one.     This may have some complications; your paren matching logic may have to worry about various types of quoting in the C++ code.  For instance,

```
        {   //   this } isn't a match
```

and

```
        {   char x[]="} this isnt a match { either" }
```

Other C++ string quotes may make this even more difficult to see.  What will you do about a C++ macro used like this?

```
        {
        #define rcb }
            {   rcb
        }
```

You'll will probably have to make some special rules about how } is processed in the embedded C++ code, and your character-by-character scanning will have to know this rule.

Rather than make this complicated, I think what you should do is pick a really unlikely sequence of characters in C++ as your termination, e.g.,

```
    ][[
```

which I believe cannot occur in C++ except in a string or comment, or

```
    }}}
```

and simply use that.  No need to match parens at all.  In almost all cases, the C++ to drop in won't have to be touched; in the rare, rare case where it happens to contain that sequence an trivial edit (insert a space or linebreak) fixes it.  Now your lexer rule is simple and can be expressed (I think) using your standard lexer.

If you go this way, I'd suggest you chose a corresponding opening sequence to introduce the C++ code, just to remind the reader that a funny sequence is required, e.g.,

```
  serial {{{    <C++code>  }}}
```

or

```
  serial ]][   <C++code>   ][[
```

With this convention, even my ugly macro example is easy:

```
  serial {{{
      {
      #define rcb }
         {  rcb
      } 
  }}}
```

PS: This funny notational trick is called a "domain (notation) escape".  This problem occurs in every system (yes not that many in the wild, but I have one :) that allows one to mix multiple notations.  The sequence varies across language/system according to taste.

Comment: Delimiter-matching is indeed how our parser works (see lines 987-1015 [here](https://charm.cs.illinois.edu/gerrit/gitweb?p=charm.git;a=blob;f=src/xlat-i/xi-grammar.y;h=1183166e516630cc29c167f66788549abce527b7;hb=HEAD#l987)). However, the context issue remains as the lexer simply doesn't have enough information on its own to determine when to emit special C++ tokens that can be used by the grammar.

Also, we handle all your three cases in the existing tool through preprocessing, but they would indeed need to be addressed here as well.

Comment: The key problem is isolating the blob of C++ text from your DSL.  You can make it harder by insisting your DSL be parsed, and that same parser somehow parses the C++ for "special C++ tokens".   (Do you mean C++ identifiers that name functions and variables?)   I think that way lies madness; partial parsers are called "island parsers" in the literature, and in my experience have never been very effective, partly because with a complex language like C++ you have to know how lex/parse it pretty well just to decide what to reliably ignore.

Comment: Unfortunately we have a legacy issue that would make it infeasible to change delimiters (though it would certainly make our lives much easier!), especially since the original tool has worked well for so long. By "special C++ tokens" I mean our CPROGRAM tokens that the lexer returns when it knows it's within C++ code blocks due to a flag toggled in the grammar context. All the parser knows about C++ is that it should match delimiters between CPROGRAM tokens -- braces within serial blocks, parentheses within special for-loop blocks, square brackets in top-level array variable declarations, etc.

Comment: So you *did* build an island parser; you have to reliably recognize the various brackets and when they are valid, and when they are not (e.g., they're in a comment or string literal.  That sounds like a pain to code, and gives the worst representation of the C++ program:  a sequence of bracket tokens intermixed with C++ text blobs; that's unparseable so all it is good for is bracket matching, and that doesn't handle my macro example.  It doesn't seem like a great solution.

Comment: This approach makes me uneasy as well, but the comment/string issues have been surprisingly easy to handle on the existing tool (and we run a C++ preprocessor as a first step, so the macro definition goes away.) They also don't show up on the Xtext-generated lexer, which likely handles strings and comments with something like ANTLR's lexer modes. Ideally we would just hand over the C++ text blobs to an external library for e.g. content assist as any more meaningful C++ parsing functionality would be many orders of magnitude more complex than our simple high-level coordination DSL requires.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot change the syntax and need to rely on matching curly braces, than you need to reimplement your flex-based solution in Java (e.g. use jflex) and make Xtext use that lexer.
I have covered that briefly in this [blog post](http://typefox.io/taming-the-lexer). It also contains a pointer to example code where I have used a jflex based lexer in Xtext.

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample code! However, how can Xtext tell jflex to change lexing modes (as in our flex approach)? The only other way I see to do this is by making the lexer be a lot more context-aware, but I feel that starts leaking the grammar abstraction. For example, [here](https://charm.cs.illinois.edu/gerrit/gitweb?p=charm.git;a=blob;f=examples/charm%2B%2B/matmul/matmul.ci;h=3ab426a38f400f27955156ca5324386cc457b04d;hb=HEAD#l20) we have a construct like this: "forall [...] (C++:C++, C++)". In a lexer-only approach, it would have to be intimately aware of the grammar.